# Synthetic smarts

Tags: riddle, cipher

I have encoded a riddle. Everything necessary to decode the riddle is supplied below. There are two parts to the puzzle: Decode the riddle, then solve the riddle.

MSSCMMEMESSQGMGSESSWGSGGMCGQMMMSWMCKASSGCGMESMCGBSKSM

1010010010000010010110011001000100000100100101100100010110011000100100010000011000100101100101100010011000

Hint 1:

> How would someone with no knowledge of complex ciphers or matrices approach the ciphertext? Think in simple terms.

Hint 2:

> Nothing represented by the binary is greater than two.

I will add more hints if necessary.

Comment: Initial observation: Alphabetic string is 53 chars long. Binary is 106 chars long. 106/2 = 53.

Comment: Just curious- why am I being downvoted? Is it too easy?

Comment: People are likely downvoting because of http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do/

Comment: Interestingly enough I read that post before I submitted this puzzle, and did not believe it contravened any rules established.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message is

> OUTCOME OF TURING TEST WITHIN CHRONOSYNCLASTIC INFUNDIBULUM

The method of encipherment:

> The first step is to realize that every block of two binary digits corresponds to one letter. We can then group as follows:
> `M,10 S,10 S,01 C,00 etc.`
> All we then do with these groupings is 'increment' the letter by the number represented by the binary in its group. For instance, the first group is `M,10`, and 10 is 2 in binary, so two letters after `M` is the first letter of the plaintext `O`.
> Continuing like this we get:
> `OUTCOMEOFTURINGTESTWITHINCHRONOSYNCLASTICINFUNDIBULUM`

Comment: Decryption is spot on, an error on my part caused TURINI to be plaintext, should be TURING. I will fix that in the question, good job though. The riddle has been decoded, but has yet to be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess for the riddle decoded by Tryth:

> Chronosynclastic infundibulum is a term used in ["The Sirens of Titan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sirens_of_Titan), and refers to a place in which one's existence in space-time becomes fragmented, being able to appear at multiple locations and time points simultaneously. This grants some humans within this space the ability to know the past and the future. In such a case, the [Turing test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test), which tests whether an artificial intelligence can be sufficiently advanced so as to be indistinguishable from a reasonable human being, becomes exponentially more difficult, i.e. the outcome is almost always a failed test.

> It's also possible that the riddle is referring to the [halting problem for testing Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which is a decision problem that is known to be undecidable for a general class of computers (called Turing machines). If this is true, then "the outcome of Turing test" refers to a computer within the chronosynclastic infundibulum that overcomes this limitation.

Comment: The first answer is correct. The test itself(and thus the outcome) is being observed from within the chronosynclastic infundibulum, but does not take place within it. Therefore the outcome of the test performed at any arbitrary time can only be known by the observer until it is performed, and the nature of outliers one way or the other is proportional to the point in time being observed. The most accurate way to describe the outcomes is they are trending towards always failing, and since all points are already known, this is fairly intuitive.